# JS: Create ruby tags from japanese/kana input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create HTML ruby tags for a Japanese text with JavaScript.

I have a field with the Japanese text (Kanji and kana, parameter "jap") and I have a field with this Japanese text in kana-only (parameter "kana"). I didn't find any JavaScript for this purpose so I wrote one by myself. It's an ugly monster of code and I would like to know if there's a simpler way to do that.

```
function isKanji(ch) {
    return (ch >="\u4e00"&& ch <="\u9faf") || (ch >="\u3400"&& ch <="\u4dbf");
}

function showRuby(jap, kana) {
    var id_ruby=document.getElementById("jap_ruby");
    var id_jap=document.getElementById("japaneseid");
    jap+=" ";
    kana+=" ";
    var res="";
    var kanji="";
    var furi="";
    var i;
    var iK=-1;
    for (i=0;
    i < jap.length;

    i++) {
        iK+=1;
        var charJ=jap.charAt(i);
        var charK=kana.charAt(iK);

        if (isKanji(charJ)) {
            //kanji, set result
            res+=((isKanji(jap.charAt(i - 1)) !=true)) ? "<ruby>"+charJ: charJ;
            furi+=charK;
        }

        else {

            //no kanji, if character before was kanji, get furigana, else set result with kana
            if (isKanji(jap.charAt(i - 1))) {
                //here the furigana for the kanji before, continue loop for kana until they match
                for (iK;
                iK < kana.length;

                iK++) {
                    charK=kana.charAt(iK);
                    charKnext=kana.charAt(iK + 1);
                    charJnext=jap.charAt(i + 1);

                    if (charK==charJ) {

                        //check if kana belongs to furigana or if it matches the kana in jap
                        if (isKanji(charJnext) || (charKnext==charJnext)) {
                            //kanji furi match
                            res+="<rt>"+furi+"</rt></ruby>"+charK;
                            furi="";
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    furi+=charK;
                }
            }

            else {
                //set result with kana
                res+=charJ;
            }
        }
    }

    id_ruby.innerHTML=res.trim();
}
```

Let's say, jap = "歯医者さん行かなきゃ" and kana = "はいしゃさんいかなきゃ", then the output should be 歯医者さん行かなきゃ inside ruby tags with the matching furigana on top of each kanji group.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the excellent diff-match-patch library from Google. We get the diffs between the two strings; where they're equal, no furigana is needed. If they differ, we'll combine them in a `<ruby>` tag when the next equal segment comes. I push an extra "equal" segment to force any stored furigana to show up.

```js
const japanese = "歯医者さん行かなきゃ";
const hiragana = "はいしゃさんいかなきゃ";

function furigana(japanese, hiragana) {
  const diffs = new diff_match_patch().diff_main(japanese, hiragana);
  let html = '', ruby = { furigana: null, text: null };
  diffs.push([0, '']);
  diffs.map(([kind, text]) => {
    if (kind == 0) {
      if (ruby.furigana || ruby.text) {
        html += `<ruby>${ruby.text}<rp>(</rp><rt>${ruby.furigana}</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>`;
        ruby.furigana = null;
        ruby.text = null;
      }
      html += text;
    } else {
      ruby[kind == 1 ? 'furigana' : 'text'] = text;
    }
  });
  return html;
}

document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = furigana(
  "歯医者さん行かなきゃ",
  "はいしゃさんいかなきゃ");

document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = furigana(
  "天使さんがOLとして働いています。", // works even for romaji...
  "エンジェルさんがオーエルとしてはたらいています。");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/diff_match_patch/20121119/diff_match_patch.js"></script>
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great and doesn't even need to check if the character is a Kanji or not. But I want to use the script in Anki and would prefer a solution that doesn't need to load an extern script.

Comment: Doesn’t have to be external. You could even paste the content of the library into the page inside a script tag if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a simple way to put the furigana above the kanji easily without all the ruby tags, I've developed a way that seems to work easily and seems to work in all the browsers that I tested using only CSS and HTML.  It makes a custom HTML tag and works really simple and nice.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style>
fg:before {
 content: attr(t);
 display: block;
    font-size: 50%;
    text-align: start;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

fg {
 display: inline-block;
 text-indent: 0px;
 line-height: normal;
    -webkit-text-emphasis: none;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<fg t="わたし">私</fg>はケンです。<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```